How to create index for metadata field in Pymongo time series
My time series object:
{
    "timestamp": datetime object,
    "field1": "somestring",
    "metadata": {
        "type": 1,
        "location": "Hong Kong"
    }
}

And I create a index for my metadata field:
collection = db.create_collection(
    "market-catalog-time-series",
    timeseries={
        "timeField": "timestamp",
        "metaField": "metadata",
        "granularity": "seconds",
    },
)
db.collection.createIndex('metadata')

After that I wish to query the data:
res = db.collection.find({"metadata": {"type": 1, "location": "Hong Kong"}})
print(list(res))

however, I got [], may I ask why?

TL;DR: Remove the db. prefix and do only res = collection.find(...) or db.get_collection("market-catalog-time-series").find(...). Explanation: You are creating a collection called market-catalog-time-series and assigning it to the variable collection, which already has an assigned/parent db from db.create_collection(...). But then in res = db.collection.find(...) it means the collection named collection for db, the parent db, that collection probably doesn't exist but is different from the one you want. Same issue for db.collection.createIndex('metadata').

TL;DR: Remove the db. prefix and do only res = collection.find(...) or db.get_collection("market-catalog-time-series").find(...).
Explanation: You are creating a collection called market-catalog-time-series and assigning it to the variable collection. That already has a parent db from db.create_collection(...).
But then in res = db.collection.find(...) it means the collection named collection for db, the parent db. That collection probably doesn't exist and is different from the one you want.
Same issue for db.collection.createIndex('metadata'). The actual method is create_index() not createIndex(). And it should be just collection.create_index('metadata') or db.get_collection("market-catalog-time-series").create_index('metadata')
So the full code would be:
collection = db.create_collection(
    "market-catalog-time-series",
    timeseries={
        "timeField": "timestamp",
        "metaField": "metadata",
        "granularity": "seconds",
    },
)
collection.create_index('metadata')

res = collection.find({"metadata": {"type": 1, "location": "Hong Kong"}})
print(list(res))

